# convert model property value with javascript in razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a foreach to iterate through items in razor syntax,

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ColorCode)
        </td>
        <td>


            <div style="background-color:*************">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>


        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

ColorCode is an int value
,i define an external function named IntToColorHex to convert ColorCode to equivalent hex value,i want to replace ************** with an hex color value for each row according to ColorCode,i need some thing like bellow:

```
<div style="background-color:IntToColorHex(@item.ColorCode)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: you can just do tostring in razor without js function, see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString), so enough something like `background-color:#@item.ColorCode.ToString("X6")`

Comment: thanks,but i create IntToColorHex function in external .js file that linked to my view ,item.ColorCode must pass to this function to calculate new value and then set it to background-color

Comment: you can't call js function inside html style attribute

Comment: ok , thanks to your help

Comment: Why you want call js function, instead just render needed value on server?

Comment: i new to asp and java script ,this is my test sample,i think to an other way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87095/discussion-between-grundy-and-hossein-ab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call js function from style attribute, so this line

```
<div style="background-color:IntToColorHex(@item.ColorCode)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
```

just render to something like

```
<div style="background-color:IntToColorHex(100000)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
```

But you can use simple [ToString with hexadecimal ("X") format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString) like

```
<div style="background-color:#@item.ColorCode.ToString("X6")">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
```